# Filling a 2D array from 1D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to learn C. I want to fill a 2D array from a 1D array that I have got from a File.

Now, I am trying to take the elements of array pointer(output:Hello,My,name,is,Ram.) into a 2D array called words. the purpose is to remove commas and highlight each word in a different row. I have achieved that too However I am getting some gibberish along with my output. I have checked my entries one by one and found that the first line(Hello,My,name,is,Ram.) is stored in from row 1 to 5 in word[]. However, the next line(I,own,20,thousand,bucks.) starts at row [10] of word that I don't understand why? plus my output looks weird with some unknown values. Please inform me what should I do to correct my output and size the 2 D array equal to the value it contains

Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    FILE *fp;
    char (*points)[50];
    char *array;
    int width=20,height=50;
    char *word;
    char words [width][height];
    int counter=0; // To traverse through array and tracks the current position in array.
    points = malloc(sizeof(*points) * 2);

    word=malloc(width*height*sizeof(char));
    if (points == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(0);
    }
    fp = fopen("/Users/shubhamsharma/Desktop/data.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fgets(points[0], sizeof(*points), fp);
    fgets(points[1], sizeof(*points), fp);
    array=points[0];
    printf("%s", points[0]);
    printf("%s", points[1]);

    for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0,p=counter;j<height;j++,p++)
        {
            if(array[p]==','||array[p]=='\0')
            {
                words[i][j]='\n';
                counter=++p;
                break;
            }
            else
                words[i][j]=array[p];

        }}

    printf("\n%c",words[16][0]);
    for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {

            if(words[i][j]=='\n')
            {
                break;
            }
            printf("\nPrinting element in word\n");
            printf("%c",words[i][j]);

        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);

    free(points);
    return 0;
    return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
> Hello,My,name,is,Ram. I,own,20,thousand,bucks. Printing element in word
> HelloMynameisRam.+̮\213\377\310`\267t\377̮\213\377Iown20thousandbucks.
> Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Lines in my file looks something like.-

```
Hello,My,name,is,Ram.
I,own,20,thousand,bucks.
```

Comment: Are you even aware C and C++ are different languages?

Comment: Olaf might be asking because of `char words[width][height];`, or some other construct that won't compile. We'll need to know what compiler you're using, and are you building with C or C++.

Comment: I am building with C using XCODE . I am sorry I thought that logic might be the same in C and C++

Comment: Logic is, but syntax is not. The meaning of statements in C++ is not identical, but if your files end in .c and not .cpp, XCode will apply flags for C, so that's covered. Posting an answer for more material...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is missing `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`.

After that, your code allocates memory correctly; but you never use `word` so it could be removed.

Your code reads the first line correctly. However, after the condition `array[p] == '\0'`, the next time you enter the `j` loop it just keeps reading junk from `points[0]`, after the end of the data read by `fgets`. This causes undefined behaviour, you're lucky the results were even as coherent as they were.

You need to have extra code for the `array[p] == '\0'` case to move `array` onto reading the next line, e.g. `array = points[1]; p = counter = 0; break;`.  (Actually `p` is redundant in this loop, you could just use `counter` directly)

This will involve an extra variable to track which index of `points` you are up to, and ensure you do not go off the end.

A better approach would be to only read each line as you are processing it: get rid of `array`, have a single buffer `char line[50];`, and call `fgets` at the start and then each time you have reached the `'\0'` on processing that line.

(Your whole algorithm could be much improved but I'll leave that to you: part of learning is to do things the way you think of, and see what the pros and cons are of what you end up with, and then try to improve it on your own).

Finally, your code for displaying the strings is wrong. `words[16][0]` might be past the end of what you read depending on the input file, and you currently print `Printing element in word` before *every single character*.  Your sample output you posted in your question doesn't show this, so I guess the code you posted does not match the code you were testing this.

Instead I would suggest that you update your "reading" code to null-terminate the strings (use `words[i][j]='\0';` instead of `words[i][j]='\n';`), and then you can use standard functions to print them:

```
for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
    printf("%s\n", words[n]);
```

---

[Here](http://ideone.com/EDvGFx) is your code working with the minimal changes I  have suggested.  I put in some debugging `printf` lines that you can un-comment to see how it is working, and I change to use `stdin` instead of opening a file so that it can be seen working in the online compiler.  You can still do a lot to improve your code! (for a start, deal with the extra `\n` which `fgets` leaves in the buffer).

Answer (score 0):

There's much to discuss, perhaps too much for an answer as stackoverflow would prefer, so let me just run down the issues which jump out.

`char words[width][height];`

I can't see how this would compile for you. The two integers width and height are not constants, which is required when allocating in this way.

This is different in C++ than in C, which is why it's critical we pin down exactly what you're using to compile, and if you intend to write in C and not C++.

Assuming C, you'll need to have some means of defining these two. Perhaps:

```
#define WIDTH 20
#define HEIGHT 50
```

Though, I've long left C behind for C++, I see no other way in a C compiler.

Then,

```
int width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT;
```

This is just to be certain there's only one place to get these values from. Now

```
char words[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

Will compile. This declares an array of 20 character arrays, each 50 bytes long. This would correspond to it's usage in the rest of your code. The two words chosen seem reversed in meaning to me, because we usually think of rows as a height, while the strings in each row would seem a length (or a width), but that is of no real concern. Otherwise, this is ok.

However, this brings us to

```
points = malloc(sizeof(*points) * 2);
```

This doesn't make sense following this declaration for points:

```
char (*points)[50];
```

I can't quite surmise what this intends. The compiler seems to think this is a `char[50] *`, a pointer to an array of 50 bytes, but that's because of the parenthesis around `*points`. It appears you may have placed that there to stop a compiler complaint when it's absent.

This declaration would be an array of 50 pointers to char (or 50 char * in a row);

```
char * points[50];
```

Which means the compiler would not accept:

```
points = malloc(sizeof(*points) * 2);
```

However, what it would allow is:

```
points[0] = malloc( sizeof( *points ) * 2 );
```

Which is how you use this later in the code. This did not do what you expected. What you are allocating is 100 bytes (on most compilers), which is two times the size of `*points`, indicating you wanted room for two character arrays of 50 bytes each. What you got, however, is one character array of 100 bytes.

That's important because in the code you use it with:

```
fgets(points[0], sizeof(*points), fp);
fgets(points[1], sizeof(*points), fp);
array=points[0];
printf("%s", points[0]);
printf("%s", points[1]);
```

This USES `points[1]`, but there is nothing allocated at points[1]. Factually, I'm not sure what the compiler generated, the code in its original form would not compile, but for points to be used in this way requires two pointer assignments, not one.

```
points[0] = malloc( sizeof( *points ) );
points[1] = malloc( sizeof( *points ) );
```

Might make the usage above valid, though it's not clear why the size is based on the points array, perhaps it's a little more logical to say

```
points[0] = malloc( HEIGHT );
points[1] = malloc( HEIGHT );
```

So that points might be more reasonably declared

```
char * points[2];
```

Which is how it has been used.

To be clear, in the code provided, there is no clear way that the use of `points[0]` and `points[1]` made sense. The use of `char * array;` later indicates you expect the two `fgets` operations to place the content in a contiguous block of RAM, which could be arranged, but not reliably in the way constructed here.

It may have SEEMED to work when you printed the two lines

```
printf("%s", points[0]);
printf("%s", points[1]);
```

But it really does look more like a side effect than a plan.

Based on your use of array in the following:

```
for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
{
    for(int j=0,p=counter;j<height;j++,p++)
    {
        if(array[p]==','||array[p]=='\0')
        {
            words[i][j]='\n';
            counter=++p;
            break;
        }
        else
            words[i][j]=array[p];

    }
}
```

It appears what you intended was something more like:

```
array = malloc( HEIGHT * 2 );
```

After which this might have done what you expected.

```
fgets( array, HEIGHT * 2, fp );
```

from which you COULD (why I'm not sure) align points with

```
points[0] = array;
points[1] = array + HEIGHT;
```

I should point out, too, that it does not appear in the loop above that you deal with zero termination of strings.

That would mean that words might contain garbage unless every word is 19 characters with a terminating `\n` and no zero termination.

Consider these points and perhaps we can edit this to advance your plan in code.

Comment: This is pretty much all wrong.  Array dimensions do not have to be constants. `points = malloc(sizeof(*points) * 2);` is correct. If you don't recognize basic declarations like `char (*points)[50];` I'd suggest refraining from answering questions about it.

Comment: M.M you should avoid being rude and presumptive. `char (*points)[50];` will generate a compiler error when followed by `points = malloc(sizeof(*points) * 2);` in VS2015. Try it and find out. Further, VS2015 refuses `char words[width][height];` complaining constants are expected. Did anyone specify which compiler? No.

Comment: VS is well known for not implementing C properly. If you are giving a VS-specific answer you should say so .  OP said in comments that he is not using VS, and you acknowledged that and then wrote "I can't see how this would compile for you", so your "defence" that it doesn't work in VS is obviously bogus.  BTW, retaliatory voting is against SO policy.

Comment: MSVC 2013 in C mode [accepts](http://rextester.com/EWREWN56188) `char (*points)[50]; points = malloc(sizeof(*points) * 2);`, so you should report a bug if MSVC 2015 doesn't

Comment: No problem. I've decided I'm not returning to stackoverflow. Just not worth it.